# Euler Substitution

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

Got a math problem that i have to solve using Euler substitution but at one point I'm getting stuck. Tried different ways of solving, can't figure out.
The problem sounds like that:

$$
\int_{0}^{1} \frac{1}{x + \sqrt{x^2 + x + 1}} \, dx
$$

Tried to substitute the square root with $x + t$, tried with $t - x$, but no success. Can someone give me a hint where I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: Both of those substitutions work. Can you say what went happened when you attempted one or both of them?

Comment: can you edit the question showing where you're stuck? I'll be easier helping you

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I suspect you got stuck when computing $dt$ for $t=x+\sqrt{x^2+x+1}$,
$$dt=\left(1+\frac{2x+1}{2\sqrt{x^2+x+1}}\right)dx=\frac{2t+1}{2(t-x)}dx.$$
What do we do with the $x$ that is left over? Express it in terms of $t$:
$$(t-x)^2=x^2+x+1\implies x=\frac{t^2-1}{1+2t}.$$
Can you finish?

Comment: I get stuck after this step, so I do $$
dx = \frac{2t(t+1) - (t^2 - 1) \cdot 2}{(2t + 1)^2} \, dt
$$
   Simplify that to $$
dx = \frac{2t^2 + 2t + 2}{(2t + 1)^2} \, dt
$$
And rewrite the initial integral in $$
\int_{0}^{1} \frac{2t^2 + 2t + 2}{(2t^2 + 1) \cdot t} \, dt
$$
 And as I'm writing that I figured that now I have to write it as simple equasion $$
\int_{0}^{1} \left( \frac{A}{t} + \frac{Bt+C}{(2t+1)^2} \right) \, dt
$$ Am I going in the right dirrection?

Comment: You have typos/mistakes in all but the second equation; 3rd equation is correct except you put the square inside parenthesis, not outside; also need to fix limits of integration. From there, I would certainly try partial fractions...

Comment: @Valentin Although I would suggest that if you are stuck solving this $t$ integral that you ask a new question and link this one as a reference. That way it is clear that you have a new problem. Hope my answer was helpful.

Comment: I solved it, thank you! Will post the final answer later on when I will grt back to my computer.

Comment: @Valentin excellent! If you are satisfied with an answer, you can accept it by clicking the green checkmark.

Answer (score 5):

Substitute $t={x + \sqrt{x^2 + x + 1}}$

Then transform the integral (change of variable) in terms of $t$. You'll then get a not-so-difficult integral which you can easily solve.